# Apex 5.1 form page item won't accept a pl/sql function body for default value

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I get an error message saying my code has a problem when trying to use a pl/sql fucntion body in form item.
Here is my pl/sql function body:

```
declare 
    v_name_default varchar2(50);
begin
    select name into v_name_default from staff_names where upper(net_id)=:APP_USER;
    return v_name_default;
end;
```

I wonder if perhaps the :APP_USER variable is not allowed -- I am trying to have the default value be the NAME of the individual who is using the form rather than their ID (net_id)

RESOLUTION FOUND:

I was able to resolve the problem.  The function body was fine, but the Userid I was pulling from the table was not there.  I needed to put some error trapping in my function body to capture those situations.  Once I made sure the userid I was testing was in the table, the function worked fine.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Oracle usually doesn't sound *poetic* and is rather specific when raising an error. Moreover, it provides error code (the ORA-xxxxx) along with a message. So, yes - as Blurryface has told you, we do need some more information. Because, I've just written code similar to yours, and default value works just fine.

Comment: I resolved the issue. See my edit to my question.  Thanks for the comment.  The Oracle message was not clear -- just told me the page could not be accessed due to the error.